# Nexus registry as an http docker mirror

Tags: docker, nexus

We have a nexus3 server with a docker proxy configured for http use.

On the clients, I added --registry-mirror http://thenexus:8082 and when I try to `docker pull alpine:3.4` for example, I get in the logs ->

```
level=error msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: Get http://thenexus:8082/v2/library/alpine/manifests/3.4: no basic auth credentials"
```

But if I `curl http://thenexus:8082/v2/library/alpine/manifests/3.4` it works so I don't need credentials.

I'm using docker 1.12.2 on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: At the moment you do need credentials:  https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-10813

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Does anyone know how to configure docker to transmit the credentials?